# How to stop the method from returning null once finished going through the ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, oop, arraylist, return

I'm having a problem with my code, where I go through an `ArrayList` and get `currentVehicle` and return it to display in a GUI interface.

I'm having issues when reaching the end of the `ArrayList` and it begins to return 'null'. As it returns 'null' I can't go back to previous vehicles, as the `currentVehicle` value is now assigned as 'null'.

I have tried using `while` loops to restart the loop, `else, and else if` loops and using `lastIndexOf` and `isEmpty` to check the `ArrayList` and attempt to get it to re-loop.

Below is the code for the `ArrayList` in which I'm searching for the next vehicle in the list, and where I believe the fix may exist.

Showroom.java

```
 public Vehicle nextVehicle()
    {  
        Vehicle nV = null;

        try
        {      
            if (currentVehicle < vehicleArray.size())
            {
                nV = vehicleArray.get(currentVehicle++);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("No more vehicles listed");
        }   

        return nV;
    }
```

GUIMain is where the output is happening and I'm printing to a JPanel TextArea

GUIMain.java

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() == nextButt)
        {
                log.setText(null);
                log.append("" + s.nextVehicle());
        }

    }
```

`log.setText(null);` clears the `JPanel` textbox for the next Vehicle to be displayed and `log.append("" + s.nextVehicle());` prints the currentVehicle onto the `JPanel` `TextArea`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any other code is needed or a SSCCE is required I'll go ahead and get it done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you want to go back to the first Vehicle once the last one is reached, do the following :

```
public Vehicle nextVehicle()
    {  
        Vehicle nV = null;

        try
        {      
            if (currentVehicle < vehicleArray.size())
            {
                nV = vehicleArray.get(currentVehicle++);
            } else {
                if (vehicleArray.size() > 0) {
                    nV = verhicleArray.get(0);
                    currentVehicle = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("No more vehicles listed");
        }   

        return nV;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code (and intent) you could do,

```
return vehicleArray.get(vehicleArray.size()-1);
```

Of course, if the `vehicleArray` is null (or empty) the above code won't work. Java-8 (and guava) have [`Optional<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for this,

```
public Optional<Vehicle> nextVehicle() {
    if (vehicleArray != null && !vehicleArray.isEmpty()) {
        return Optional
                .ofNullable(vehicleArray.get(vehicleArray.size() - 1));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```